# How does exploring work in Steep?

Tags: achievements, steep

There is an achievement for getting 100% explored but im not sure how this works. I assume they don't expect you to move across every inch of the mountains, its confusing me.

Comment: Generally, with achievements like this. You have to discover every point of interest

Comment: Oh that makes more sense, that's allot of exploring then haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the pause menu you can see on the left side your % exploration progress. It is broken down into drop zones, challenges, and points of interest. So while Taacoo's comment is somewhat correct, it also includes the other two categories.

Each location type shows the total number that exist and the number you have discovered.

For 100% completion, I recommend finding drop zones first to unlock the challenges. Play the challenges next which often intersect points of interest. This isn't foolproof though, because I have unlocked and played nearly all challenges and still need to find a dozen or so POI.

Once you reach level 25, you have unlimited helicopter passes, so you can drop in to any point of the mountain whenever you want. That makes it easy to find glaciers or towns from the map to drop in and unlock the POI. It's a big mountain though, so even that isn't a piece of cake.

Comment: i managed to 100% exploration and im almost at 90% completion for the game, its really fun actually. Just cant wait for what they add in next.

Comment: Also, the Map view shows you the number of Drop Zones, Challenges and Points of Interest found out of the total number for each mountain area.